# Group by calculating the non-breaking periods from two (from and to) values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by, connect-by

Which Oracle SQL-technique is possible to use for concatenate this rows:

```
id | from | to
--------------
 a |   20 | 25
 a |   26 | 30
 a |   32 | 40
 b |    1 |  5
 b |    7 | 10
 b |   11 | 20
```

for such result:

```
 a |   20 | 30
 a |   32 | 40
 b |    1 |  5
 b |    7 | 20
```

? Assumed that `from` and `to` is start and end of an integer period, and necessary to choose an non-breaking periods for `id`'s

Just looking for right direction and example, can this be done using `group by` or `connect by` or something else?

DB is `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.6.0 - 64bit Production`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something similar:

```
select
    field_id,
    min(field_from),
    max(field_to)
from (
    select
        field_from,
        field_to,
        field_id,
        sum(willSum) over(partition by field_id order by field_from) as GID
    from (
        select
            field_from,
            field_to,
            field_id,
            case when field_from
                    = Lag(field_to) over(partition by field_id order by field_from)
                 then 0 else 1 end as willSum + 1
        from
            rj_mytest
        )
    )
group by
    field_id,
    GID
order by
    field_id,
    min(field_from);
```

There are a few similar example: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/969005

Comment: You've forgotten `partition by field_id` at line #10

Comment: @Lajos Veres, you are missing a `+ 1` in the case statement.

Comment: @Lajos Veres, appears that this method doesn't depend on the data type, I have no problem to replace the `field_from`, `field_to` from `number` to `date` type, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, max("from") as "from", max("to") as "to"
from (
  select 
    nvl(prv.id, nxt.id) id,
    nxt."from", 
    prv."to", 
    nvl2(nxt."to", 
      row_number() over (partition by nxt.id order by nxt."from"), 
      row_number() over (partition by prv.id order by prv."to")) rn
  from t prv full join t nxt on
    prv.id = nxt.id and prv."to" + 1 = nxt."from"
  where nxt."to" + prv."to" is null 
)
group by id, rn
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b35d/1)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, which uses `model` clause to assign a group number to a consecutive pairs of values:

```
select id1
     , min(from1) as from1
     , max(to1)   as to1
  from (select *
          from t1
          model
          partition by (id1)
          dimension by (row_number() over(partition by id1 order by from1) as rn)
          measures(from1, to1, 1 as grp)
          rules(
              grp[rn] = case
                          when from1[cv()] = nvl(to1[cv()-1] + 1, from1[cv()]) 
                          then nvl(grp[cv() - 1], 1)
                          else grp[cv() - 1] + 1
                        end 
               )
)
group by id1
       , grp
order by id1
       , from1
```

Result:

```
ID1      FROM1        TO1
--- ---------- ----------
a           20         30 
a           32         40 
b            1          5 
b            7         20
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/89f87/1)

Comment: and if I tested rightly, if remove just only `+ 1` from line 12, then will be able to handle same end/start of ranges? (a, 20, 25), (b, 25, 30), (a, 30, 40)